# Concurrent Modification Exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am getting the following `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on this method

```
private AtomicReference<HashMap<String, Logger>> transactionLoggerMap = new AtomicReference<HashMap<String,Logger>>();

public void rolloutFile() {

    // Get all the loggers and fire a temp log line.
    Set<String> transactionLoggerSet = (Set<String>) transactionLoggerMap.get().keySet();
    Iterator<String> transactionLoggerSetIter = transactionLoggerSet.iterator();
    while(transactionLoggerSetIter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) transactionLoggerSetIter.next();
        Logger txnLogger = transactionLoggerMap.get().get(key);
        localLogger.trace("About to do timer task rollover:");
        txnLogger.info(DataTransformerConstants.IGNORE_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Please suggest, if I am using a Atomic Reference, how do i get a como?

Answer (score 9):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` means that you have modified the collection outside of the iterator.  I don't see any modifications in your loop so I assume that there is another thread that is also adding or removing from the `transactionLoggerMap` at the same time you are iterating across it.

Even though you have it wrapped in an `AtomicReference`, you still cannot have two threads making changes to the same unsynchronized collection at the same time.  `AtomicReference` does *not* synchronize the object it is wrapping -- it just gives you a way to atomically get and set that reference.

You will need to make this a synchronized collection either by using the `ConcurrentHashMap` class or wrapping your `HashMap` using the `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` method.

Comment: This is all correct but could be wrong in this particular question's context, as the `get` call may be changing the structure of the map. More here: http://goo.gl/f3faP

Comment: The OP is talking about a `HashMap` which is not an access ordered map @paranoid, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not protecting against concurrent modifications during your iteration. The Atomic reference only makes sure you get your Map (and it's contents).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider iterating over a local copy of the collection instead of the same collection. It would be an easy way to ensure your collection will not be modified while you're looping over it. It is advisable to use immutable objects on a multi-threaded environment and you prevent this kind of problems for free.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redundant
 `Set<String> transactionLoggerSet = (Set<String>) transactionLoggerMap.get().keySet();`
You would still have to use synchronization as you are iterating over the map. SynchronizedMap  guarentees consistency for its API methods. For the rest, you would need to do client side synchronization